# php using file_get_contents with an array

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents

I am trying to pull values from the following url: https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices

What I want to accomplish:
Obtain all the "symbol" values printed in the website (one under the other)

The result I am looking for, would be:

```
ETHBTC
LTCBTC
...
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($content, true);

for ($i=0; $i < count($json_data); $i++) { 
    # code...
    print_r($json_data);
}
?>
```

The result it brings is the entire data (the symbols, prices, plus other irrelevant data).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foreach` loop, then echo the value by `symbol` key

```
$url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($content, true);

foreach ($json_data as $value) {
    echo $value["symbol"] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Erwin. How would it work if instead of all the full values list. I would just like to get one item of the array? example, the first array item.
Something like echo $value["symbol[0]"] ?

Comment: if you just want one value, you can skip the loop and print it directly. E.g. `echo $json_data[0]["symbol"];` wherein, `[0]` means the first set of array inside `$json_data`

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it:

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($content, true);

for ($i=0; $i < count($json_data); $i++) {
    echo $json_data[$i]['symbol'] . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, 
     
How would it work if instead of having all the list values displayed in the website, I just wanted to have specific list values displayed? Example: I want to have displayed the array item that has the symbol "LTCBTC"

Answer (score 0):

```
json_data["symbol"]
```

instead in the print

Comment: Like this? print_r($json_data["symbol"]);

Comment: does not work Notice: Undefined index: symbol in line 26